# Adding int to character provides unexpected results

Tags: c

I'm encrypting a message (just the letters and digits) with the caesar cipher and reversing the result. As I'm shifting by a set number of letters, if that number is negative, the shift will be to the left. To simplify this case, I tried to use modulo so that the result will be a shift right that leads to the result of the desired left shift. The issue is, when I increase the value of a character by an int, the result is sometimes higher than is should be.
For example, when I added 19 to a character equal to 'l' (lower case 'L') it resulted in the char equivalent of 177.

I've tried using all other data types than int, but they all result in the same issue. Testing this with a single character not part of an array functioned the way it should have.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char valid(char pass[16])
{
    if(strlen(pass)<8)return 0;
    char oka=0, okA=0, ok0=0, okspc=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(pass);i++)
        if(pass[i]==' ')
            return 0;
        else if(pass[i]>='a'&&pass[i]<='z')
            oka=1;
        else if(pass[i]>='A'&&pass[i]<='Z')
            okA=1;
        else if(pass[i]>='0'&&pass[i]<='9')
            ok0=1;
        else
            okspc=1;
        return (oka&&okA&&ok0&&okspc);
}
int modulo(int x, int y){
    return (x%y+y)%y;
}
void encrypt(char *msg, int shift)
{
    int shifta=modulo(shift, 26), shiftd=modulo(shift, 10);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(msg);i++)
        if(msg[i]>='A'&&msg[i]<='Z')
        {
            msg[i]+=shifta; ///Problematic line
            if(msg[i]>'Z')
                msg[i]-=26;
            /*else if(msg[i]<'A')
                msg[i]+=26;*/
        }
        else if(msg[i]>='a'&&msg[i]<='z')
        {
            msg[i]+=shifta; ///Other problematic line
            if(msg[i]>'z')
                msg[i]-=26;
            /*else if(msg[i]<'a')
                msg[i]+=26;*/
        }
        else if(msg[i]>='0'&&msg[i]<='9')
        {
            msg[i]=(int)msg[i]+shiftd;
            if(msg[i]>'9')
                msg[i]-=10;
            /*else if(msg[i]<'0')
                msg[i]+=10;*/
        }
    strrev(msg);
}
int main()
{
    char msg[255], pass[16], aux[16];
    int shift;
    printf("Enter password (max 16 characters): ");
    fgets(pass, 16, stdin);
    while(!valid(pass))
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Password is not valid, please retry.\nEnter password: ");
        fgets(pass, 16, stdin);
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("Password is valid!\nPlease type in a message to encrypt/decrypt (max 255 characters):\n");
    fgets(msg, 255, stdin);
    printf("Please enter caesar encryption/decryption shift: ");
    scanf("%d", &shift);
    system("cls");
    getchar();
    printf("Thank you!\nPlease enter the password: ");
    fgets(aux, 16, stdin);
    while(strcmp(pass, aux))
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Password is wrong, please retry.\nEnter password: ");
        fgets(aux, 16, stdin);
    }
    system("cls");
    encrypt(msg, shift);
    printf("Password is correct!\nThe encrypted/decrypted message:\n%s", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

I could not retrieve the output from the console as it printed some strange characters.

Comment: Do you know what the numeric value of `'I'` is (the value you added 19 to to get 177)?

Comment: It was lower case 'L', which is 108 in ASCII

Comment: When I add 19 to 'l' I get 127, can you produce a minimal example?

Comment: in spy movies they never care about lower / upper case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch about not using the right data type was correct. Here:

```
    msg[i] = msg[i] + shifta;
```

you are doing the calculation with a `char`, which on your system is probably signed. A lower-case letter from the rear of the alphabet with a high enough shift will go beyond the maximum possible value of 127 and result in a negative value. The comparisons that you use to shift back the letters into a valid range won't be true: The negative value is never greter than `'z'`.

You can fix this with an intermediate `int` valiable:

```
    int x = msg[i] + shifta;

    if (x > 'z') x -= 26;
    if (x < 'a') x += 26;

    msg[i] = x;
```

Another possibility is to do the arithmetic in one go, so that the intermediate result isn't truncated by storing it in a narrower data type:result

```
    msg[i] = 'a' + (msg[i] - 'a' + shifta) % 26;
```